# Image is assigned to another row item of ListView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, async-await

I know async await is very handy to prepare data for a ListView/GridView before its adapter is set. For example:

```
// in Activity.cs
async void OnCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState)
{
    SetContentView(...);
    ListView listView = FindViewById<ListView>(...);
    AdapterData data = await Task.Run(() => GetDataFromWorkerThread);
    listView.SetAdapter(data);
}
```

But what I need is :

```
// in ListViewAdapter.cs
public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    if(convertView == null) 
    {
        // create new view
    }
    ImageView imgView = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resouce.Id.img_view_id);
    ResizeImageAsync(imgView, imgResId);
    return convertView; // convertView is returned before ImageView is assigned with resized image
}

private async void ResizeImageAsync(ImageView imageView, int imgResId)
{
    Bitmap bmp = await Task<Bitmap>.Run(() => ResizeImage(imgResId, 50, 50));
    imageView.SetImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

So sometimes `convertView` in `GetView()` is returned before `ResizeImageAsync()` is finished. The problem is `image01` which was supposed to be assigned in first row's `ImageView` is now instead being assigned to the second or third row's `ImageView`. Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: try using Picasso. It will handle caching and async loading for you!

Comment: Thank you @Pavlos, could you please tell me what Picasso is.

Comment: http://square.github.io/picasso/ Pretty simple and easy to use!

Comment: Just noticed you are using C# here is a link for the same project in C# https://github.com/jacksierkstra/Picasso

Comment: May i make it an answer ?

Comment: Sry @Pavlos, I tried Picasso c# version, but that doesn't compile, I got the error: Squareup.OkHttp.HttpResponseCache.Get()' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62021/discussion-between-macio-jun-and-pavlos).

Comment: Can you modify your `GetView` method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is not that view is returned but that it goes out of screen and is reused. Then you fire up another async method and last finished wins. That said you have to cancel the first one of you start another on same view. One solution is to use CancellationTokenSource which you store in View.Tag. That gives you a way to cancel previously not finished async method.

Here is a not-really-tested-for-syntax-errors code.Note that storing a .net object into View.Tag requires a wrapper. Also note that this code might not be perfect but it should illustrate what to do.

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            // create new view
        }
        else
        {
            if (convertView.Tag != null)
            {
                var wraper = convertView.Tag.JavaCast<Wrapper<CancellationTokenSource>>();
                if (wraper != null)
                    wraper.Data.Cancel();
            }
        }
        ImageView imgView = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.img_view_id);
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        ResizeImageAsync(imgView, imgResId, cts.Token);
        convertView.Tag = new Wrapper<CancellationTokenSource> { Data = cts };
        return convertView; // convertView is returned before ImageView is assigned with resized image
    }

    private async Task ResizeImageAsync(ImageView imageView, int imgResId, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = await Task<Bitmap>.Run(() => ResizeImage(imgResId, 50, 50), ct);
        if (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            imageView.SetImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
    }

    public class Wrapper<T>: Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public T Data;
    }
```

Comment: I would give you 10 upvotes if I could. btw could you please confirm my understanding? The reason why "image01" is set to the other row's ImageView is that when convertView is non-null in callback GetView(), convertView could be both row 1's and row 11's RowView, because of view reuse in ListView. If we scroll from row 1 to 11, thread 1 is spawned to set image01 to row1's ImageView and thread 2 is spawned to set image11 to row11's ImageView, but sometimes thread1 ends after thread 2 ends. So the shared convertView for both row 1 and row 11 is now  displaying image01 instead of image11.

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much what happens.

Comment: Thank you very much Miha. You helped me so much in both Xamarin android and Xamarin Form :D

Comment: You're welcome. One more thing, when using async make sure you return a Task if possible (not void) because it might crash when Exception occurs (even cancellation) otherwise.

Comment: Thank you Miha, never knew about that. I will definitely return only Task instead of void in the future.

Comment: Not to be too dorky, but using async void has the same end result (exception-wise) as using async Task which is awaited and that is because async void is treated as a top level async method and will have it's exception handled (or unhandled) on the main thread.  Anyhow your answer was great @MihaMarkic.