# Using an async method in a GridView adapter GetView method

Tags: android, gridview, asynchronous, xamarin, getview

I am coding a Xamarin Android application, and I have a question in relation to a `GridView` adapter.

Is it possible to use the `async` keyword with the `GetView` method? I have an `await` function that I wish to use in the `GetView` method that retrieves images asynchronously for each `GridView` item?

Currently the method is:

```
public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

I am looking for something equivalent to:

```
public async override Task<View> GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
'SimpleMapDemo.GridViewWithImageAndTextAdapter.GetView(int, Android.Views.View, Android.Views.ViewGroup)': return type must be 'Android.Views.View' to match overridden member 'Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.GetView(int, Android.Views.View, Android.Views.ViewGroup)'
```

Is this possible? If not, is it possible to launch a background process in each `GetView` method to retrieve the required images asynchronously, or should I try another approach?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use await because you have to access UI from the UI thread and thus it doesn't make sense to use async method. There isn't such a method as well.

That said the other option you mentioned is the way to go. Here, see my answer here [Image is assigned to another row item of ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070455/image-is-assigned-to-another-row-item-of-listview/26074609#26074609)

Comment: Your other answer which you linked to is much better than using `ContinueWith`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `ContinueWith()` on your awaitable method (as long as it returns a `Task`).

```
...
YourMethod().ContinueWith(t => 
   {
      //Whatever you need to execute when YourMethod() finishes
   });
...
```

Here's [more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx) on `ContinueWith()`

Answer (score 0):

You could run your task like this:

```
Task.Run(async delegate() => {
       await AsyncMethod().ContinueWith(() => {
          Context.InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                //DO YOUR UI STUFF HERE!!
               });
       });
});
```